# Set pdf form field value using docusign while user sign PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, docusignapi

I am using Docusign in .Net core and angular.

I have PDF and in that one field is Date, please check image for reference..

So I want to set that field value when user sign in PDF from Signing URL..

So is there any way where we can set values in PDF form field.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While it seems like you want to use a Date tab for this, a Date tab is limited in such a way. Its value cannot be set. It is always going to be the date/time when the user signed the envelope.

If your requirement is to set the value of a date field programmatically, you will need to use a Text tab and set its value.

The [following article](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/set-envelope-tab-values/) shows how to do that, the relevant C# snippet to set a Text tab value is this (change to the Value you want):

```
    Text textFamiliar = new Text
    {
    AnchorString = "/familiar/",
    AnchorUnits = "pixels",
    AnchorYOffset = "-9",
    AnchorXOffset = "5",
    Font = "helvetica",
    FontSize = "size11",
    Bold = "true",
    Value = "Your value here!",
    Locked = "false",
    TabId = "familiar_name",
    TabLabel = "Familiar name",
    };
```